# Angularjs Default routes in html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my multi languages angular app, I want the default to be English

This is my routes

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/en");
//
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/{lang:(?:he|en)}',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    }).state('app.home', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/home.html",
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
```

The `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` worked as expected, and if i enter to my domain
http://example.com
the URL changed to http://example.com/#/en

My problem is that i change the routes to html5Mode (for seo)

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In the html5Mode when i enter to my domain http://example.com, the URL doesn't change to http://example.com/en as expected.

In short how can i add default routing in html5 mode?

Thanks

Comment: `url: '/{lang:(?:he|en)}',` missing `/` at end.

Comment: unbelievable! so simple, thanks!